# Applying a Grails filter to login URL

Tags: grails

In my Grails 2.5.X app I'm using the Spring Security REST plugin and have configured the login URL like so in `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/internal/login'
```

I need to apply a filter to this URL and am attempting to do this with

```
class GrailsFilters {
    def filters = {
        login(uri: '/internal/login') {

            before = {
                // implementation omitted
            }

            after = { Map model ->
                // implementation omitted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But for some odd reason the filter never gets called. Is there something special about the login endpoint which means it can't be filtered?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is something special about it. It uses a servlet filter (chain there of) which have a higher priority than the Grails filter you are trying to use.

If you need to intercept the call you'll need to create your own filter in the Spring Security filter chain. The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#filters) has an entire section that goes into the details.